# MageStackDay #5 is happening on the 17th & 18th of June 2016

Tags: discussion, community, magestackday, event

Back by popular demand: MageStackDay #5 is going to take place on the **17th & 18th of June 2016**!

MageStackDay is an online hackathon dedicated to answering, closing and cleaning up questions on magento.stackexchange.com. The goal will be to get the answered questions rate up by at least a few percent and get more users active on this platform.

**Sign up & win**

Sign up [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1hhI27f3Ek4xHm5jc_gohFutBcsK2tHMmekokyYxyR2M/viewform) for MageStackDay #5!
We'll be giving away 2 (2x1) Meet Magento tickets to everyone who signed up for MageStackDay :-)

Comment: Yay! Let's do this !!

Comment: Greats Annn.I will join with yours

Comment: Good stuff, I will try and get more people involved!

Comment: Here we gooo.... wohoo.. :)

Comment: this post is so META

Answer (score 3, accepted):

264 Questions answered!
With the help of over 60 participants we answered 264 questions and earned 212 badges, giving out 573 votes.

And that's something to be really proud of. It's a real community effort.

Thanks to everyone who participated and supported MageStackDay #5!

Check out these pages for more information:

- http://magestackday.com/2016/06/18/magestackday-5-thank-you/
- http://magestackday.com/2016/06/19/magestackday-5-statistics/

We hope to see you for another MageStackDay in the future!